# IUriToStreamResolver for WebBrowser Control (WPF)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, webbrowser-control

One of or legacy applications (WinForms), uses the WebBrowser-Control for displaying html files. The html document itself has a lot references to other files (css, js, images, etc.). All files – including the html file itself - are located in a zip file and should stay in there. So extracting the files is no option.

During a current refactoring phase we will switch the GUI to WPF and do other optimizations as well. One of this optimizations concerns the resolving of the referenced files of our html documents. Right now we use a custom protocol implementation which has a lot of Interop and other things I want to get rid of if possible.

Lately I discovered a nice new feature in WinRT. The **IUriToStreamResolver** interface. The interface defines just a single method – UriToStreamAsync. An implementation of that interface can be passed to **NavigateToLocalStreamUri** of the WebView control and handles the resolving of all resources loaded into the WebView.

Is there any way to accomplish something like this in a normal .Net WPF Application or do we have to stick to our old custom protocol approach? Has anybody experiences with that kind of scenario?

Regards
Dominik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had simular problem few years ago, but did not found acceptable solution for IE control. But you can use Chromium Embedded Framework for Sharp or Gecko Sharp. As I remember they have such methods. Bad for me, they haven't enough methods for my purpose, but may be they acceptable for you.
Or you may just leave as is, Asynchronous Pluggable Protocol isn't so bad.